# Join (large) files on alphanumeric pattern

Tags: text-processing, awk, join

I have:

File 1 like:

```
sting_of_printable_characters*sting_of_printable_characters*sting_of_printable_characters*ALPHANUMERIC_PATTERN
```

File 2 like:

```
sting_of_printable_characters*ALPHANUMERIC_PATTERN
```

where `*` is a field separator and the alphanumeric pattern is always the last field in the line.
I am completely stumped on how to achieve the following and would appreciate some assistance.

I need to essentially "join" (I've tried the `join` command and it doesn't seem to work with alphanumeric keys) these two files based on "ALPHANUMERIC_PATTERN", and only print where both files contain the same ALPHANUMERIC_PATTERN.

I would prefer to use `awk` due to it's processing efficiency but anything would be very helpful.  (These files are large.)

The catch is that I need to see the output similar to the below:

```
ALPHANUMERIC_PATTERN*stuff_from_file_1*stuff_from_file_2
```

Comment: What does `*` in the sample data represent, is it a separator? Does it always separate strings of printable characters from alphanumeric pattern at the end?

Comment: I should have mentioned this - * is a field separator. And yes the alphanumeric pattern is always the last field in the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `join` you could try like this:

```
join -t\* \
<(sed 's/\(.*\)\(\*\)\(.*\)/\3\2\1/' file1 | sort -t\* -k1,1) \
<(sed 's/\(.*\)\(\*\)\(.*\)/\3\2\1/' file2 | sort -t\* -k1,1)
```

The two `sed`s move the last field to the beginning of line, e.g.

```
field1*field2*...field(N-1)*field(N)
```

becomes

```
field(N)*field1*field2*...*field(N-1)
```

the results are then then `sort`ed on `1`st field and then `join`ed (always on `1`st field). This will print lines like:

```
field(N)*fields(1)to(N-1)*from*file1*fields(1)to(N-1)*from*file2
```

If you prefer working with temporary files and save `join` result to e.g. `outfile`:

```
sed 's/\(.*\)\(\*\)\(.*\)/\3\2\1/' file1 | sort -t\* -k1,1 > sorted_1
sed 's/\(.*\)\(\*\)\(.*\)/\3\2\1/' file2 | sort -t\* -k1,1 > sorted_2
join -t\* sorted_{1,2} > outfile
rm -f sorted_{1,2}
```

Comment: This solution in working with temporary files worked perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can join on the last field directly as long as the number of fields is fixed:

```
join -t \* -1 4 -2 2 file1 file2
ALPHANUMERIC_PATTERN*sting_of_printable_characters*sting_of_printable_characters*sting_of_printable_characters*sting_of_printable_characters
```

Off course both fields need to be sorted on the field you wish to join them on.
If not you can use the technique don_crissti showed

```
joint -t \* -1 4 -2 2 <(sort -k4 file1) <(sort -k2 file2)
```